# Dbf to sql datetime not importing

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, dbf, dbase

I am converting all of our databses from dbase visual foxpro files over to sql server. the `.dbf` table that I'm having trouble with has a bunch of character fields and a `datetime` field. I have created an equivalent table in SQL-server that has all the same sized fields and a `datetime` field. however when I go to import the `.dbf` file into sql-server, it immediately gives me this error:

[image]

the visual foxpro datetime data looks like this though:

[image]

and the field properties in visual foxpro look like this:

[image]

Is the datetime in sq-server different than the datetime in a .dbf file? I dont understand what the error message is saying. How do i make it so I can import this table with out issues? any help is appreciated

thank you

Comment: What version and edition of SQL Server?  Also, you appear to be using a third party utility.  Perhaps the problem is there?

Comment: @EricHauenstein the front end is AnySQL Maestro, but it runs on MS SQL server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully used the Sql Server Upsizing Wizard tool from the free Sedna pack Microsoft release for VFP. It runs from withing Visual FoxPro to upload all your data to Sql Server.

Note: If you DBF tables are not in a DBC, you'll need to make a copy of the tables and index in a seprate folder, then add the tables to a DBC, then you can use the Upsizing Wizard.

http://vfpx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sedna#SQLServerUpsizing

Also, here's an article from CODE Magazine on how to use it:
http://www.codemag.com/article/0703052